# Create in php a multi level category by taking data from the database mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have database table that has these values:

```
ID  and  SUB  
--       --

1         0
2         0
3         0
4         0
5         0
```

Now from php/mysql I'm trying to do this: if I put for example the value of ID to SUB, to create a `<ul><li></li><ul>` level. For example: 
if `ID=5` has `SUB=1`, then I should have

```html
<ul>
  <li> 1
    <ul><li> 5 </li></ul>
  </li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

If, for example, `ID=1` has `SUB=2`, then I should have:

```html
<ul>
  <li> 2
    <ul><li> 1 
      <ul><li>5</ul>
  </li></ul>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your schema follows the "adjacency list" model of representing hierarchical data in an RDBMS, which requires recursion to achieve your desired result.  Unfortunately, unlike some other RDBMS, MySQL does not support recursive functions—so, as things stand, you'd have to implement this in PHP (which will be slow).  You should consider adopting a different model, such as "nested sets" or "a transitive closure table".  See Bill Karwin's excellent presentation, [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data), for more information.

Comment: I'm trying to do it completely from php, but lost in if and while statements.